# How to bind tibbles by row with different number of columns in R

Tags: r, bind

I want to bind `df1` with `df2` by row, keeping the same column name, to obtain `df3`.

```
library(tidyverse)

  df1 <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3),
                b = c(4, 5, 6),
                c = c(1, 5, 7))
  
  df2 <- tibble(a = c(8, 9),
                b = c(5, 6))
  
  # how to bind these tibbles by row to get
  
  df3 <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3, 8, 9),
                b = c(4, 5, 6, 5, 6),
                c = c(1, 5, 7, NA, NA))
```

Created on 2020-10-30 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using `bind_rows()` from `dplyr`. Updated credit to **@AbdessabourMtk**:

```
df3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     1
2     2     5     5
3     3     6     7
4     8     5    NA
5     9     6    NA
```

Comment: he wants to bind df1 and df2, otherwise this is the correct answer

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Many thanks, I have updated with credits to you!

Comment: no need to credit me.

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Any contribution to help others always need to be recognized!

Answer (score 2):

A base R option

```
df2[setdiff(names(df1),names(df2))]<-NA
df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

giving

```
> df3
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     1
2     2     5     5
3     3     6     7
4     8     5    NA
5     9     6    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#   a b  c
#1: 1 4  1
#2: 2 5  5
#3: 3 6  7
#4: 8 5 NA
#5: 9 6 NA
```